How to calculate the risk ratio and 95% confidence interval of an interaction term (using R)
My goal is to calculate the risk ratio and 95% confidence interval for the interaction terms.
For example, there are two variables age and sex (y ~ age * sex), and I want to calculate the hazard ratio and 95% confidence interval for age increment for males and females respectively.
Here is an example I made using the rms package. If my understanding is correct, summary.rms of the rms package can easily output the risk ratio of the interaction term by summary(f, age = ..., sex = "Female/Male").
The effect for the age interaction can be calculated as the exponential transformation of coefage for the first level (in this case, females), the exponential transformation of coefage + coefage:Male (males), and if there are other levels then of coefage + coefage:other.
As for the standard error, I saw the following calculation formula on the Internet: $\sqrt{\text{var}(b_1) + \text{var}(b_2) + 2\text{cov}(b_1,b_2)}$.
The result of this formula is consistent with the output of the rms package. However, it seems that some people have pointed out that this formula has no basis (see this)?
My question is,

Are the calculation method and formula I described correct?

Is this calculation method and formula applicable to general linear regression, logistic regression and cox regression? (Is it a universal method?)

Interactions are very common. Many people will divide the data into several subgroups according to the categorical variable and then calculate the effect of the continuous value respectively. But this method should be wrong, right? The interaction should be calculated in the whole sample, and then the effect of the continuous value at different levels should be calculated according to the above method (a little off topic, I want to confirm whether my this understanding is correct).


require(survival)
require(rms)
n <- 1000
set.seed(1)

sex <- factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n, 
                     rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4)))
age <- 40 + 11*rnorm(n) + as.numeric(sex) *rnorm(n)
cens <- 14*runif(n)
h <- .12*exp(.04*(age-40)+.72*(sex=='Female'))
dt <- -log(runif(n))/h
e <- ifelse(dt <= cens,1,0)
dt <- pmin(dt, cens)
dd <- datadist(age, sex)
options(datadist='dd')
S <- Surv(dt,e)

f <- cph(S ~ age * sex, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
f
# Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
# age             0.0273 0.0053  5.15  <0.0001 
# sex=Male       -1.4011 0.3025 -4.63  <0.0001 
# age * sex=Male  0.0174 0.0070  2.48  0.0130  

summary(f, age = c(40,41), sex = "Female")
summary(f, age = c(40,41), sex = "Male")
# Effects              Response : S 
# 
# Factor            Low High Diff. Effect  S.E.      Lower 0.95 Upper 0.95
# age               40  41    1    0.04471 0.0046908 0.035516   0.053903  
# Hazard Ratio     40  41    1    1.04570        NA 1.036200   1.055400  
# sex - Female:Male  2   1   NA    0.71319 0.0831390 0.550240   0.876140  
# Hazard Ratio      2   1   NA    2.04050        NA 1.733700   2.401600  

f$coefficients[1] + f$coefficients[3] 
# 0.04470962

v <- vcov(f)
sqrt(v["age", "age"] + v["age * sex=Male", "age * sex=Male"] + 2*v["age", "age * sex=Male"])
# 0.004690838


